# How to show moodle iomad company name as sub-domain in url?

Tags: moodle, multi-tenant

I am using Iomad for multitenancy feature in moodle.
I have created companies using iomad and added user into it .

i want to see these company as url like
www.mydomain.com/company1
www.mydomain.com/company2 
or some thing
else but company  should be shown in url.
So that each company have its own url and user can login from that url.

Comment: iomad is a custom version of Moodle. http://www.iomad.org/os-download/ You might be better asking them directly, maybe here:  https://github.com/iomad/iomad/issues